# Converting string to dates where month and/or day is missing

Tags: r, date

I have partial dates. I want to paste 1st day if day is missing and 01JAN is day and month is missing and then convert it to date object with ymd:

```
aa = data.frame(a = c("2021-01", "2021"))
bb = aa %>%
  mutate(aa = case_when(nchar(a) == 7 ~ ymd(paste(a, "-01", sep = "")),
                        nchar(a) == 4 ~ ymd(paste(a, "-01-01", sep=""))))
```

Could you please advise me why I'm getting these warnings?

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `aa = case_when(...)`.
ℹ  1 failed to parse. 
2: Problem while computing `aa = case_when(...)`.
ℹ  1 failed to parse.
```

I changed paste to paste0, used truncated and it didn;t work. I have to use lubridate. With base R and as.Date it works.

Answer (score 1):

try doing it outside of the case when. The reason why your example is failing is that `ymd()` wants to work on the whole column of characters instead of part of it. `case_when()` returns the *values* when it is true and `FALSE` otherwise.  when using `ymd()` inside the `case_when()` it sees the *values* that meet the condition and then also `FALSE` values when it does not meet the condition.  Try this to reproduce your error.

`ymd("2020-01-01",FALSE)`

As mentioned by @Cettt , `as.Date()` just isn't producing a warning but the results are the same.

```
 library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
aa = data.frame(a = c("2021-01", "2021"))
bb = aa %>%
  mutate(aa = case_when(nchar(a) == 7 ~ paste(a, "-01", sep = ""),
                        nchar(a) == 4 ~ paste(a, "-01-01", sep="")),
         aa = ymd(aa))
```

Comment: Why outside? And why when I replace ymd with as.Date (inside case_when) it work without warnings?

Comment: @rashette I tried to explain a bit more

Answer (score 1):

The warnings have to do with the way `case_when` operates.
It first computes all the cases for all the rows and then only returns the relevant cases.
In your case you get warnings because e.g. the first case does not produce a that in the second row.

Try this instead

```
bb = aa %>%
  mutate(
    aa = ymd(case_when(
      nchar(a) == 7 ~ paste(a, "-01", sep = ""),
      nchar(a) == 4 ~ paste(a, "-01-01", sep ="")
)) 
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. So why when I replace ymd with as.Date() it work without any warnings?

Comment: Probably because as.Date('2021-01') does not produce a warning

Answer (score 1):

`as.Date` will ignore junk at the end so use this or apply `format` to that if a character vector is needed.

```
aa <- data.frame(a = c("2021-01", "2021"))
as.Date(paste0(aa$a, "-01-01"))
## [1] "2021-01-01" "2021-01-01"
```